# Uploading Aheadworks blog extension to my custom Magento theme

Tags: magento, blogs

I'm fairly new to Magento and am having trouble uploading the Aheadworks blog extension to the correct directories. I am using a custom theme for my site, let's call it "themex". The directions state "Navigate inside step_1 directory. If you use a different from default theme - be sure to rename step_1/app/design/frontend/default/default and step_1/skin/frontend/default/default folders to your store's values."

I've located the 'step_1' directory but I'm not quite understanding the latter part of the directions. Am I renaming the 'step_1' directory to "themex" and uploading it to the root directory? Please be as descriptive as possible in your response.

Answer (score 0):

Their instructions are badly phrased, but I'm pretty sure it means that you need to upload the files to app/design/frontend/default/themex

Magento theme files appear in the app/design/frontend/ folder.

The "base" folder here contains the core layout files, and the "default" folder contains the file overrides for other themes.  As such, your theme's layout files will appear under app/design/frontend/default/themex  (possibly app/design/frontend/themex/default depending on how the theme works)

Magento will first look for design files here first, and then look under app/design/frontend/base if the override does not exist.

Make sure you back-up any files, and if their files over-write any of your theme files then run a comparison on them to make sure they are not over-writing any of your theme's functionality.

Comment: Might be worth a read to expand on this - http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy